# "RemoveRange" for bulk delete in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, delete-row

I am looking for opportunities to delete at once several objects.The normal delete occurs when object state marked for delete and `SaveChanges()` method called.But it should be loaded in memory.How can I avoid this? I know I can attach object with specified id and then delete it, but I need more complex queries using expressions.Using sql command on `DbSet` is not option for me,as I don't want manually fix field names if they will change.I would like to use the power of ORM. I have noticed method `RemoveRange` but it takes `IEnumerable` as input, which means it wouldn't use expression tree. So, is there any extension method (nuget) or ORM support for deleting by expression tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [EntityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended).

**Samples**

```
context.Users
    .Where(u => u.FirstName == "firstname")
    .Delete();

context.Tasks
    .Where(t => t.StatusId == 1)
    .Update(t => new Task { StatusId = 2 });
```